# IntelliJ error messages for Maven Plugin Annotations

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, annotations

I am getting incorrect error messages in IntelliJ for a Maven plugin I am creating.

I have the following dependencies in my pom:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am using IntelliJ 12.0

The incorrect errors are in the screenshot. does anyone know what can cause this?

the code runs just fine with a `clean install`

[image: maven incorrect errors]

Comment: The scope is "provided" , that means the library is coming from the container. Is IntelliJ correctly pointing at you container?

Comment: yes, and the dependencies show up correctly in the left hand menu under "External Libraries"

Comment: Can you try hitting from the right tab of IntelliJ "Maven Projects" and clicking on the first 2 buttons: "Reimport All Maven Projects" and "Generate sources and Update Folders for All Projects"?

Comment: @AndreiSfat tried it now, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Vegard, another question: If you open your pom.xml and look through the file, are all of your dependencies okay? What I mean by this is if the dependencies are not marked in red, as being not found in the m2 repo? Maybe one more question would be if you enabled Auto-Import in IntelliJ for your Maven project? You can enable such feature going to Settings > Maven > Importing, there is a checkbox that says "Import Maven projects automatically".

Comment: @AndreiSfat The pom has no errors, and autoimport does not seem to help

Comment: @Vegard how about importing the pom.xml to a new workspace ?

Comment: @AndreiSfat reimported the entire project now, but that did not seem to work. Other annotations shows correctly, and the project still runs just fine with clean install

Comment: @Vegard just created a quick project locally, added the same dependencies, created a similar class as you did in your example and I had no problems. My next suggestion would be to delete your local ~/.m2/repo. And maybe reinstall Intellij without reimporting your old settings and start fresh. AFAIK, I didn't do any special settings in IntelliJ's settings in regards to Maven, so really not sure what is the problem here :)

Comment: @AndreiSfat I deleted the related parts of my ~/.m2/repo, and it actually worked. Now I get all the annotations without erros. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @AndreiSfat you may write the last bit as a anwser so others can see this is a nice workaround for others who encounter the same problem. and again, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Vegard glad I could help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete your local `~/.m2/repo`. And maybe reinstall Intellij without reimporting your old settings and start fresh.